# android webview upload from gallery working but not from camera Code missing?

Tags: android, file, input, file-upload, webview

Android Studio 2021
SDK 30

I have a working webview with GPS, share, etc, file upload ask camera or gallery.

My code works when the user choose a existing file in gallery, but when take from camera, nothings happens

It also request usual permissions from the user

Here AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIDEO_CAPTURE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"  />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
       <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
@SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;
    private String mCameravideoPath;
    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    // FOR FILE UPLOAD
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }

            Uri[] results = null;
            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null || data.getDataString() == null) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        String[] permissions = {
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        };

        requestPermissions(permissions, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        String appNAME = getString(R.string.app_name);
        String stubdomain = getString(R.string.stubdomain);

        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);

        // FOR FILE UPLOAD
        mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

        // WEBCHROME
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new AppTheWayChromeExtended() {

            // FILE UPLOAD
            private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

                int timeStamp = (new Random().nextInt((1000000 - 1) + 1) + 1);
                String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
                File storageDir = getCacheDir();
                return File.createTempFile(
                        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                        storageDir      /* directory */
                );

            }

            private File createVideoFile() throws IOException {

                int timeStamp = (new Random().nextInt((1000000 - 1) + 1) + 1);
                String videoFileName = "VID_" + timeStamp + "_";
                File storageDir = getCacheDir();
                return File.createTempFile(
                        videoFileName,
                        ".mp4",
                        storageDir
                );

            }

            @SuppressLint("QueryPermissionsNeeded")
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
                if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mFilePathCallback = filePath;

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        // Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the video should go
                    File videoFile = null;
                    try {
                        videoFile = createVideoFile();
                        takeVideoIntent.putExtra("VideoPath", mCameravideoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        // Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (videoFile != null) {
                        mCameravideoPath = "file:" + videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
                    } else {
                        takeVideoIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*, video/*");
                contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[]{"image/*", "video/*"});
                contentSelectionIntent.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "image/* video/*");

                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null && takeVideoIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent, takeVideoIntent};
                } else if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else if (takeVideoIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takeVideoIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Upload");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
                return true;
            }

        });

        mWebView.loadUrl("https://filebin.net/");

        this.setContentView(mWebView);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater myMenuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        myMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.super_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.myMenuOne:
                onBackPressed();
                break;

            case R.id.myMenuTwo:
                GoForward();
                break;

        }
        return true;
    }

    private void GoForward() {
        if (mWebView.canGoForward()) {
            mWebView.goForward();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't go further!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

While reading on the web I found stuff about file_path.xml, but I tried different values without success

```
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="extfiles" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="external" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="my_videos" path="." />
    <external-media-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <external-media-path name="extfiles" path="." />
    <external-media-path name="my_images" path="." />
    <external-media-path name="my_videos" path="." />
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <external-path name="extfiles" path="."/>
    <external-path name="external" path="."/>
    <external-path name="my_images" path="."/>
    <external-path name="my_videos" path="."/>
    <files-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <files-path name="extfiles" path="."/>
    <files-path name="external" path="."/>
    <files-path name="my_images" path="."/>
    <files-path name="my_videos" path="."/>
    <files-path name="files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

......................

EDIT: 2021-03-07

I added log.e like this

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                        Log.e("imgFileU", "247 "+mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        Log.e("imgFileU", "250 Unable to create Image File", ex);
                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                        Log.e("imgFileU", "257 "+mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
```

And I got in the log

```
2021-03-07 16:18:58.556 7705-7705/com.... E/imgFileU: 247 null
2021-03-07 16:18:58.556 7705-7705/com.... E/imgFileU: 257 file:/data/user/0/com...../cache/JPEG_809310_3070323002224129302.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to use intents instead of implementing specific details.  A button [or anything really could start the process].  An easy example to understand is maps,  if you have a geocode or address you start an activity for a result and you let the device open 'whatever' based on the intent.

Not clear from your code sample if you are using intents to upload a snapshot.  For example:

this in the click handler of a button should open the camera. [untested]

```
 if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new 
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new 
 File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

}

Comment: Where would I put this code to test it ? Inside onShowFileChooser or else where ?

Comment: I see you mention .getExternalStorageDirectory that is probably what I'm missing...

Comment: there is `Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {` in the code sample

Comment: I edited the question see "EDIT: 2021-03-07"..... and the log from android studio, but no image is sent to the <input type="file"....

Comment: are you ever calling the takePhoto intent?

Comment: I'm not sure what to answer to your question.... inside `onShowFileChooser` I have this code `Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null && takeVideoIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent, takeVideoIntent};
                } else if (takePictureIntent != null) {.....`

Comment: but you still need to call startActivityForResult(intent)  on that intent.  does that bring up the camera?  I noticed also that the exception handler is commented out; is there an issue there?

Comment: it opens a dialog with 3 buttons "camera" "camcorder" and "files", it I choose file, I can send without problem image or video. but when I hit "camera" I can take a picture i have "cancel" and "ok" when I hit "ok", the dialog closes, but does not update the <input type="file" value... and nothing happens there

Comment: in the code I do have `Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Upload");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
                return true;`

Comment: when you say "exception handler is commented out" you refer to what line ?

Comment: is it an alert dialog?  They can be tricky to get the response out off  what is the code on ok?

Comment: try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        // Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                    }

Comment: See the edit of my question, I uncommented it to see the log

Comment: I don't think that it's a dialog... the code for ok is inside onActivityResult `if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null || data.getDataString() == null) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } ...` I just added Log.e.... but it looks like it don't get triggered ;(

Comment: no that is not the ok for the user that is from the onActivity result.  Check if photoFile is null

Comment: I'm continuing to dig line per line and adding Log.e at many lines... I see that any Log.e located inside `if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){.... Log.e.....}` never gets triggered... that means probably that resultCode is not reached... or don't == Activity.RESULT_OK...

Comment: how can I fix this ? (note ; I know very well php, but less Android JAVA.... this code comes from many tutorials I putted together....

Comment: we could try a chat; this is alot of comments

Comment: when hit "ok" after taking a photo, the `resultCode` is 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229633/discussion-between-keeptrackofyourstack-and-jintor).

Comment: I found some clue... when a file is chosen, the result is 
 `[content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A16781]` and when a photo is taken `file:/data/user/0/com.apptheway.wexview/cache/JPEG_980041_6389888734396042298.jpg` is there a way to "convert" file:/ to [content: .....

Comment: I found out that it's most likely related to fileProvider, but because every time I try to follow tutorials, they point androidManifest.xml and add <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" ... but android is harassing me when I do that and I get TONS of deprecation ALERTS.... plus "The Android Support Library has reached the end of its life. 28.0 was the last release of the Android Support namespace and the namespace is no longer maintained" ... I have to find a new way especially to future proofing...

Comment: android x file provider is probably the way to go but the idea behind intents is sound.  Google also has an upload tutorial in its samples that may be more up-to-date, nothing in a tutorial is going to be professional quality for the most part. Kotlin is getting more attention than java for the latest examples.  Also, the issue is not so much getting the file from the camera but putting that file in an upload intent.  A coder could put a startActivityForResult(i) in one of the cases in onActivityResult, for example but it is not considered best practice to do that.

Comment: Even after using FileProvider I go through this exact same issue, I think webview and camera mix up is difficult make it work, if any one did it, do let us know